# My code is not working after upgrading three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was using three.js version r58. And below code was displaying model perfectly but after I upgraded to new version of three.js that is r73 my model not renders
In debug window it shows that mesh is there but still not visible on the screen 
Thanks if anyone could help.Code is quite lengthy sorry for that

Code:

```js
    <script src="JS/three.js"></script>

    <script src="JS/TrackballControl.js"></script>

    <script src="JS/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script>

        var container, stats;
        var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
        var objects = [];

        var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        var offset;

        var ModelData;
        var OffsetData;
        var DecompressData = { decompress: function (compressed) { "use strict"; /* Build the dictionary.*/ var i, dictionary = [], w, result, k, entry = "", dictSize = 256; for (i = 0; i < 256; i += 1) { dictionary[i] = String.fromCharCode(i); } w = String.fromCharCode(compressed[0]); result = w; for (i = 1; i < compressed.length; i += 1) { k = compressed[i]; if (dictionary[k]) { entry = dictionary[k]; } else { if (k === dictSize) { entry = w + w.charAt(0); } else { return null; } } result += entry; /* Add w+entry[0] to the dictionary.*/dictionary[dictSize++] = w + entry.charAt(0); w = entry; } return result; } };

        init();
        animate();

        function init()
        {

            container = document.getElementById("container");

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
            camera.position.z = 1000;

            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera);
            controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
            controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
            controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
            controls.noZoom = false;
            controls.noPan = false;
            controls.staticMoving = true;
            controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555));

            var light = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
            light.position.set(0, 500, 2000);
            scene.add(light);
//**************************************** b_geometry **********************
            //** modedata and offset data
            ModelData = new Array();

            tempModelData = [

            [45, 48, 46, 52, 48, 54, 50, 57, 51, 55, 51, 48, 50, 261, 49, 48, 49, 44, 48, 44, 256, 46, 56, 52, 52, 49, 279, 50, 52, 55, 54, 54, 52, 57, 53, 57, 275, 257, 259, 261, 263, 265, 267, 269, 271, 273, 273, 46, 53, 50, 260, 56, 55, 270, 54, 48, 51, 54, 51, 51, 292, 258, 260, 262, 264, 266, 268, 50, 270, 272, 49, 46, 50, 55, 316, 278, 280, 282, 284, 286, 288, 290, 316, 294, 319, 297, 322, 324, 44, 326, 328, 302, 304, 306, 308, 260, 311, 313, 315, 257, 51, 328, 52, 54, 56, 49, 56, 57, 55, 360, 304, 329, 274, 276, 331, 281, 52, 283, 285, 287, 289, 291, 276, 339, 296, 321, 299, 272, 368, 257, 370, 333, 374, 336, 291, 355, 357, 359, 361, 363, 365, 346, 345, 329, 369, 279, 371, 373, 335, 376, 338, 318, 380, 298, 323, 300, 398, 330, 401, 387, 404, 337, 391, 55, 358, 360, 362, 364, 49, 366, 301, 257, 348, 359, 350, 310, 312, 314, 302, 356, 419, 393, 422, 396, 367, 413, 332, 372, 334, 375, 417, 46, 435, 420, 394, 423, 425, 412, 427, 305, 429, 309, 352, 433, 418, 449, 438, 424, 397, 327, 399, 385, 414, 443, 388, 405, 378, 407, 320, 409, 343, 274, 454, 349, 457, 432, 354, 447, 392, 421, 395, 463, 440, 478, 456, 351, 481, 406, 295, 474, 342, 411, 465, 347, 455, 307, 480, 353, 434, 484, 450, 439, 344, 498, 489, 501, 491, 503, 460, 437, 486, 452, 509, 303, 500, 430, 458, 482, 448, 515, 451, 464, 346, 400, 442, 403, 445, 377, 293, 473, 341, 382, 508, 346, 510, 521, 492, 472, 494, 536, 410, 325, 498, 529, 402, 444, 389, 493, 340, 381, 546, 426, 519, 479, 512, 433, 543, 554, 475, 300, 384, 277, 468, 531, 552, 514, 485, 526, 488, 558, 490, 431, 513, 483, 436, 572, 507, 566, 386, 469, 416, 390, 344, 44, 50, 589, 588, 315, 52, 44, 53, 44, 54, 597, 595, 44, 329, 56, 44, 291, 270, 344, 274, 605, 325, 590, 49, 315, 281, 344, 594, 612, 344, 596, 49, 598, 49, 329, 361, 344, 603, 622, 344, 291, 305, 589, 272, 50, 590, 633, 631, 589, 315, 45, 383, 301, 639, 426, 275, 640, 368, 645, 643, 642, 477, 644, 648, 647, 642, 640, 45, 51, 327, 53, 51, 56, 267, 360, 51, 259, 55, 57, 52, 69, 639, 621, 641, 657, 50, 659, 661, 50, 663, 665, 667, 669, 620, 588, 368, 673, 675, 662, 612, 679, 668, 670, 683, 275, 685, 660, 687, 664, 48, 666, 690, 682, 650, 647, 703, 643, 640, 704, 702, 705, 301, 53, 303, 53, 49, 714, 713, 50, 51, 49, 674, 364, 681, 399, 632, 46, 55, 48, 263, 51, 713, 48, 698, 285, 308, 669, 356, 595, 712, 714, 424, 719, 718, 720, 56, 722, 651, 50, 725, 727, 314, 730, 732, 54, 734, 656, 590, 711, 53, 713, 715, 741, 719, 53, 721, 639, 723, 589, 748, 728, 751, 55, 733, 49, 735, 756, 738, 760, 717, 762, 764, 627, 642, 747, 726, 769, 270, 752, 754, 736, 647, 708, 650, 791, 643, 274, 49]];

            for (i = 0; i < tempModelData.length; i++)
            {

                ModelData = ModelData.concat((DecompressData.decompress(tempModelData[i])).split(','));
            }

            OffsetData = [55, 50, 44, 51, 54, 44, 48, 44, 256, 44, 49, 54];

            OffsetData = DecompressData.decompress(OffsetData);

            OffsetData = OffsetData.split(',');

            offset = 0;

            //End of model data and offset data

            colorVal = new THREE.Color();
            colorVal.setRGB(0.749019622802734, 0.749019622802734, 0.749019622802734);
            ambientcolorVal = new THREE.Color();
            ambientcolorVal.setRGB(0.749019622802734, 0.749019622802734, 0.749019622802734);
            specularcolorVal = new THREE.Color();
            specularcolorVal.setRGB(0, 0, 0);
            material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: colorVal, opacity: 1, transparent: false, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
            CreateandAddObject_WithNormals(+OffsetData[0], +OffsetData[1], +OffsetData[2], +OffsetData[3], 0, +OffsetData[4], material, "Part1", "");

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
            renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
            renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.sortObjects = false;
            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        }
        function CreateandAddObject_WithNormals(vertices, faceindices, colorindices, normals, uvindices, vmat, material, partName, parentName)
        {

            var matrixData;

            var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

            geometry.attributes = {

                position: {

                    itemSize: 3,

                    array: new Float32Array(ModelData.slice(offset, offset + vertices)),

                    numItems: vertices

                },

                index: {

                    itemSize: 1,

                    array: new Uint16Array(ModelData.slice(offset + vertices, offset + vertices + faceindices)),

                    numItems: faceindices

                },

                color: {

                    itemSize: 0,

                    array: new Float32Array(),

                    numItems: 0

                },

                normal: {

                    itemSize: 3,

                    array: new Float32Array(ModelData.slice(offset + vertices + faceindices + colorindices, offset + vertices + faceindices + colorindices + normals)),

                    numItems: normals

                },

                uv: {

                    itemSize: 0,

                    array: new Float32Array(),

                    numItems: 0

                }

            };

            if (uvindices !== 0)
            {

                geometry.attributes.uv.itemSize = 2;

                geometry.attributes.uv.array = new Float32Array(ModelData.slice(offset + vertices + faceindices + colorindices + normals, offset + vertices + faceindices + colorindices + normals + uvindices));

                geometry.attributes.uv.numItems = uvindices;

            }

            if (colorindices !== 0)
            {

                geometry.attributes.color.itemSize = 3;

                geometry.attributes.color.array = new Float32Array(ModelData.slice(offset + vertices + faceindices, offset + vertices + faceindices + colorindices));

                geometry.attributes.color.numItems = colorindices;

            }

            geometry.groups.push({

                start: 0,

                index: 0,

                count: faceindices

            });


            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

            mesh.name = partName;

            matrixData = ModelData.slice(offset + vertices + faceindices + colorindices + normals + uvindices, offset + vertices + faceindices + colorindices + normals + uvindices + vmat);

            offset = offset + vertices + faceindices + colorindices + normals + uvindices + vmat;

            VMat = new THREE.Matrix4(); VMat.set(matrixData[0], matrixData[1], matrixData[2], matrixData[3], matrixData[4], matrixData[5], matrixData[6], matrixData[7], matrixData[8], matrixData[9], matrixData[10], matrixData[11], matrixData[12], matrixData[13], matrixData[14], matrixData[15]);

            VMat = VMat.transpose();

            mesh.applyMatrix(VMat);

            scene.add(mesh);

        }

        function animate()
        {

            requestAnimationFrame(animate);

            render();
            

        }
        function render()
        {

            controls.update();
            renderer.render(scene, camera);

        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>WebGL viewer</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body
        {
            font-family: Monospace;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .info
        {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: black;
            opacity: 0.8;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }

            .info a
            {
                color: #00ffff;
            }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you migrate from one version of Three.js (or any library for that matter) to another, be sure to check the version migration notes - these tell you what has changed between versions and what you'll need to update in your code.

Here are Three.js's [migration logs](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration); you'll need to consider all the changes between r58 and r73. Also, as long as the version you are using (r58 for example) remains compatible with your browser and other necessary requirements, you could just keep using it as-is and then work to upgrade later as needed. It's your call.